# How do I open just a subset of very large file using vi

Tags: vim, vi

How do I open just a subset of very large file using vi

1. Open last 10000 lines using vi
2. Open 10000, 20000 lines using vi

Comment: May I ask *why* you want to do that?

Comment: For inspection and create derivatives, `tail -n 10000 | vi  -`

Comment: @JJoao How about [2]

Comment: @romainl I want to see what kind of errors are there in a very large file. I am just unable to open the file otherwise.

Comment: @Rpj (as romainl suggested) `sed -n 10000,20000p file | vi -`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not use Vim, here, because of performance issues. A pager would be better fit for the job.

1. Open last 10000 lines

   ```
   $ tail -n 10000 filename | less
   ```
2. Open 10000, 20000 lines

   ```
   $ sed -n 10000,20000p filename | less
   ```

Anyway, you can replace `less` with `vim -` if you *really* want Vim.

Answer (score 1):

In complement, I wrote a small script to edit/view a file slice (vimslice).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -s

my $file=shift or die("Error:
 usage: $0 [-n] file startline [endline]
   -n      don't save changes in file.out\n");

my $sl = shift || 1;
my $el = shift || ($sl+1000);

system("sed -n -e '$sl,$el p' $file > $file.$$");
system("vi $file.$$");

if(not $n){
  system(qq{awk '(NR==$el)          {system("cat $file.$$")}
                  NR==$sl,NR==($el) {next}
                                    {print}' $file> $file.out});}
```

After chmod and install it do

```
vimslice bigfile 10000 20000      
     ...  edit the slice, replace and save in "bigfile.out" 
vimslice -n bigfile 10000 20000        
     ...  just view the slice
vimslice bigfile 10000
     ... the same as vimslice bigfile 10000 10000+1000
```